# Clock crystal oscillator and PLL accuracy

Tags: oscillator, crystal, pll

If I use an 8 MHz oscillator with accuracy of 25 ppm and the PLL multiplies it to 32 MHz, then the accuracy is also multiplied (x4 = 100 ppm) or is it not? Thanx.

Comment: Fundamentally, it is not. However this depends on correct design of the PLL loop filter.

Comment: As @user_1818839 states, theoretical accuracy stays the same, because both the *frequency* of the oscillator and the *frequency error* are multiplied by the same amount. If an egg costs US$1, 12 eggs cost US$12, same (exorbitant) ratio.

Comment: Properly speaking (and in spite of quite a bit of current usage), if there's a PLL and frequency multiplication is happening, the whole device (PLL and divider) is a _frequency sythesizer_.  But yes, assuming it's working right if the input is off by 25PPM, then so will the output be.

Comment: ppm stands for parts per million and it doesn't scale; it's a ratio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accuracy stays the same.

If you feed in exactly 8 MHz, and PLL multiplies by exactly 4, you get exactly 32 MHz out.

If you feed in 8.1 MHz, you get 32.4 MHz out. They are both 1.25% (12500 ppm) larger than the original frequencies.